Variable metric field for delaunay computations in CGAL
is it possible to use CGAL to obtain a delaunay triangulation given ta set of points and their corresponding Riemannian metric fields. The goal is to make a triangulation that is delaunay in this variable metric field, not in Euclidean space.
Or  given a mesh and the metric field at vertices, is it possible to obtain a higher order embedding?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
I'm not sure where to begin.I have seen the concept of kernels, but it does not seem to have this option.I gave the points and metric field to BAMG, it gave a metric conforming mesh. But obviously,giving the resultant vertices of the mesh does not preserve the implied metric field.

I don't think this thesis led to a CGAL package, but I could be wrong.

Yes, they do use CGAL framework for implementation of their algorithm. I'll check it out and see how I can use it
